# Speed up computation on lists of lists in R (scalability issues)

Tags: performance, r

My goal is to take a source list of vectors and apply a mapping to each vector. The mapping creates a list of lists. When the vector size in each list element is large (~20000), and the number of elements in the source list is large (~5000), my program does not seem to be efficient. How can I optimize my code?

I've tried two things: implementation in Rcpp and mclapply. The Rcpp implementation is comparable as expected, and the mclapply implementation may not be that efficient because I'm running my function in a larger function that is already parallelized over multiple cores.

**Basic example**

```
source.list = rep(list(seq(6)),3)
target.list = list(c(1,2),c(3,4),c(5,6))

result = map_partition(source.list,target.list)

> result
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 5 6


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 5 6


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[3]][[3]]
[1] 5 6
```

**R implementation**

```
map.partition.R <- function(invec, partitionlist) {
  lst <- lapply(partitionlist, function(x) invec[invec %in% x])
  return(lst)
}

result = lapply(X=source.list, FUN=map.partition,
                               partitionlist=target.list)
```

Comment: Is `function(x) invec[invec %in% x]` what you really intend to apply or is it just here for illustration purposes? If it is really what you intend to do, I might have an idea using a data.table merge.

Comment: @flodel - it is indeed what I want to use. I want to "match" the elements of each vector in source.list and and each vector in target.list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `lapply` calls in there, so essentially two hidden `for` loops contributing to the slow execution.

Here, one way to tap into faster compiled functions is to rely on the `data.table` package for merging (a.k.a. a database join) your two data sets.

First, we turn your two lists into two data.tables:

```
idx1 <- rep(seq_along(source.list), lengths(source.list))
idx2 <- rep(seq_along(target.list), lengths(target.list))

library(data.table)
X <- data.table(id = unlist(source.list), idx1 = idx1,
                pos = seq_along(idx1), key = "id")
Y <- data.table(id = unlist(target.list), idx2 = idx2, key = "id")
```

where `idx1` and `idx2` are the variables telling us in which element of `source.list` and `target.list` a specific item (`id`) belongs. Also `pos` is just a temporary row number we will use later to sort the data back, as the next statement below (the merge) shuffles things around:

```
Z <- Y[X, allow.cartesian=TRUE]
Z <- Z[order(Z$pos)]
```

At this point, if it's possible for you, I would recommend you stop here. By that, I mean to make the next steps of your analysis use this `Z` data.table rather than a nested list, as to avoid further slow processing loops (`for/lapply/Map/etc.`). However, if you really need the nested list output, you can do:

```
no_name_split <- function(...) unname(split(...))
gp1 <- factor(Z$idx1, seq_along(source.list))
gp2 <- factor(Z$idx2, seq_along(target.list))

res <- Map(no_name_split, no_name_split(Z$id, gp1),
                          no_name_split(gp2,  gp1))
```

---

Below is a simulation with a larger dataset, comparing computation times and checking that the results are identical:

```
set.seed(632)
source.list <- replicate(500, sample(100000, 1000), simplify = FALSE)
target.list <- replicate(555, sample(100000, 1055), simplify = FALSE)

system.time({
  idx1 <- rep(seq_along(source.list), lengths(source.list))
  idx2 <- rep(seq_along(target.list), lengths(target.list))

  library(data.table)
  X <- data.table(id = unlist(source.list), idx1 = idx1,
                  pos = seq_along(idx1), key = "id")
  Y <- data.table(id = unlist(target.list), idx2 = idx2, key = "id")
  Z <- Y[X, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
  Z <- Z[order(Z$pos)]

  no_name_split <- function(...) unname(split(...))
  gp1 <- factor(Z$idx1, seq_along(source.list))
  gp2 <- factor(Z$idx2, seq_along(target.list))
  res <- Map(no_name_split, no_name_split(Z$id, gp1),
                            no_name_split(gp2,  gp1))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.394   0.382   3.646 

system.time({
  result <- lapply(X = source.list, FUN = map.partition.R,
                   partitionlist = target.list)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  23.943   5.329  36.999 

identical(res, result)
# [1] TRUE
```